# get month names between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to two dates `from` and `to`. I want to get all of the month names between these two dates.

Following is my code

```
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

function diff(from, to) {
    var datFrom = new Date('1 ' + from);
    var datTo = new Date('1 ' + to);
    var arr = monthNames.slice(datFrom.getMonth(), datTo.getMonth() + 1);
}
```

above code works for following inputs

```
diff('September 2013', 'December 2013');
```

but it does not work for this

```
diff('September 2013', 'February 2014');
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: What would you want it to do for `diff('September 2013', 'February 2015')`?

Comment: I want all the month names between those two dates.

Comment: Do you want duplicated month names was the gist of the question I believe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mine is better: http://jsfiddle.net/kS73f/8/

```
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

function diff(from, to) {
    var arr = [];
    var datFrom = new Date('1 ' + from);
    var datTo = new Date('1 ' + to);
    var fromYear =  datFrom.getFullYear();
    var toYear =  datTo.getFullYear();
    var diffYear = (12 * (toYear - fromYear)) + datTo.getMonth();

    for (var i = datFrom.getMonth(); i <= diffYear; i++) {
        arr.push(monthNames[i%12] + " " + Math.floor(fromYear+(i/12)));
    }        

    return arr;
}

console.log(diff('September 2013', 'March 2014'));
```

Comment: When I call this `console.log(diff('September 2013', 'March 2014'));` then `March` is not included in it.

Comment: updated the jsFiddle, it was an older version. changed `<` to `<=` in for loop

Comment: Yes that's good now but one thing, how can I also add year with these months. e.g. if I call `console.log(diff('September 2013', 'March 2015'));` then I need to return `month year`. How can I modify that for this?

Comment: You did not specify that in the original question.  Pick an answer, work on it some more yourself, then post again if you're still struggling

Comment: @J.P.Armstrong Can you please explain the operations in this line? I'll be grateful to you. 

arr.push(monthNames[i%12] + " " + Math.floor(fromYear+(i/12)));

Comment: @Superman, `i` is the difference in months between both dates, starting on the actual month of the 'to'. So if 'to' is Sept 2013, `i` is 8. `i%12` drops the year from the value if it goes past 12. `i/12` gets the year.

Comment: @J.P.Armstrong I used this snippet it is working fine. A little thing that I want some help is this, I'm using it to calculate the range and generating the calendar for each month. When the number of months exceeds from 12 in total. It only shows 12 months instead of up to the end date given. And this is because of i%12. What if we want to keep it going until the end date provided? Any ideas plz.

Comment: @J.P.Armstrong can i get week day name?? like 1. monday

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to do a more manual method than slice. Here's a starting point you can determine how to handle cases as mentioned in comments.

```
function diff(from, to) {
    var result = [];
    var datFrom = new Date('1 ' + from);
    var datTo = new Date('1 ' + to);
    if(datFrom < datTo) {
      var month = datFrom.getMonth();
      var toMonth = datTo.getMonth() + 1 + ((datTo.getYear() - datFrom.getYear())*12); //toMonth adjusted for year
      for(; month < toMonth; month++) { //Slice around the corner...
        result.push(monthNames[month % 12]);
      }
    }

    return result;
}

diff('September 2013', 'February 2014'); //=["September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

function diff(from, to) {
    var datFrom = new Date('1 ' + from);
    var datTo = new Date('1 ' + to);
    var arr;
    if(datFrom > datTo) {
      return diff(to, from);
    }

    var fromYear = datFrom.getFullYear();
    var toYear = datTo.getFullYear();

    if(fromYear === toYear) {
      return monthNames.slice(datFrom.getMonth(), datTo.getMonth() + 1);
    } else {
      var arr = addYear(monthNames.slice(datFrom.getMonth(), new Date('1 December ' + fromYear)), fromYear);
      for(var i = 1; i < (toYear - fromYear); i++) {
        arr = arr.concat(addYear(monthNames, fromYear + i));
      }
      return arr.concat(addYear(monthNames.slice(new Date('1 January ' + fromYear).getMonth(), datTo.getMonth() + 1), toYear));
    }
}

function addYear(arr, year) {
  var updatedArr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    updatedArr[i] = arr[i] + ' ' + year;
  }
  return updatedArr;
}
```

Than try `console.log(diff('September 2013', 'February 2015'))` to test it.

Comment: When I call this `console.log(diff('September 2013', 'March 2014'));` then it logs `["September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]`

Comment: @2619 Ups, typo. Fixed, try now.

Comment: How can I include year with the month?

Comment: @2619 Updated, try now.

Answer (score -1):

The following modifies the original function as little as possible, if that helps the OP from a comprehension standpoint.

```
function diff(from, to) {
    var datFrom = new Date('1 ' + from);
    var datTo = new Date('1 ' + to);
    var arr = monthNames.slice(datFrom.getMonth(), datTo.getMonth() + 1);

    if (!arr.length) {
        arr = monthNames.slice(datFrom.getMonth(), 12);
        arr = arr.concat(monthNames.slice(0, datTo.getMonth() + 1));
    }

    return arr;
}

console.log(diff('December 2013', 'February 2014')); //["September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February"]
```

Comment: I also want to include year with all these months. How can I do that?

Answer (score -2):

Lazy answer:

```
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", 
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

function diff(from, to) {
    var mFrom = new Date('1 ' + from).getMonth();
    var mTo = new Date('1 ' + to).getMonth();
    mTo = mTo < mFrom ? mTo + 12 : mTo;
    return monthNames.slice(mFrom, mTo + 1);
}

alert(diff('September 2013', 'December 2013'));
alert(diff('September 2013', 'February 2014'));
```