# how can I display month part only from the datepicker value

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/uScc2/10/)

When date values picked from date ranges, it need shows from - to  months like(Apr to May 2014) on the table, I added two span in my code. 
Months needs to display inside the span .

```html
<div class="top1">
  <span id="from_month"></span>
  <span id="to_month"></span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>From</label>
      <input id="min" type="text" value="2014-01-17" class="date picker" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>To</label>
      <input id="max" type="text" value="2014-01-27" class="datepicker" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="check" type="submit" name="" value="Submit" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="our_table" class="jan">
  <tr id="dte">
     <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="abc"></tr>
  <tr class="abc"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can suggest you to check this question and answer here. It might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441830/get-month-names-between-2-dates

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jQuery UI Datepicker, you can just change the [date format](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats) in the options. First result of Google will show you that.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "M, y" );
```